Depth of the filtration of higher ramification groups in the ramified case in Serre's modularity conjecture
I am studying Serre's paper "Sur les représentations modulaires de degré 2 de $\mathrm{Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)}$" and I have some questions about Serre's definition of "peu ramifiée" and "très ramifiée".
The background is the following: we have a Galois representation $\rho\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to\mathrm{Aut}(V)\cong\mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ and we restrict it to another representation $\rho_p\colon G_{p}\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, where $G_p=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$. Denote $I_p$ the absolute inertia group of $G_p$, and denote $I_{p,w}$ the absolute wild inertia group of $G_p$. We are in the case in which $I_{p,w}$ does NOT act trivially on $V$, i.e., $\rho_p(I_{p,w)}\neq\{1\}$. In this case, the action of inertia is given by
$$\rho_p|_{I_p}=\begin{pmatrix}
\chi^\beta& * \\
0& \chi^\alpha
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\chi$ denotes the mod $p$ cyclotomic character restricted to the absolute tame inertia group $I_{p,t}=I_p/I_{p,w}$, and $\alpha,\beta$ are integers such that $0\leq\alpha\leq p-2$ and $1\leq\beta\leq p-1$. Now if we assume $\beta=\alpha+1$ we can't distinguish a priori if the eigenform associated to $\rho_p$ (actually, associated to $\rho_p$ before twisting by $\chi^\alpha$ but this is not relevant in this post) has weight $2$ or $p+1$. The weight depends on the ramification of $\rho_p$, whether it is "peu ramifiée" or "très ramifiée".
In order to define these concepts, let $K_0$ be the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, let $K$ be the subfield of $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ fixed by $\ker\rho_p|_{I_p}$, and let $K_t$ the maximal tamely ramified subextension of $K/\mathbb Q_p$. One can show using the fact $\beta=\alpha+1$ that
$$\rho_p(I_p)/\rho_p(I_{p,w})\cong\mathrm{Gal}(K_t/K_0)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times. $$
I think this part follows from the fact that $\ker\chi=I_{p,w}$ and the action of $I_{p,w}$ on $V$ is given by
$$\rho_p|_{I_{p,w}}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & *\\
0& 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
because the action of wild inertia on characters is trivial. Now Serre says that the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(K_t/K_0)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ on $\rho_p(I_{p,w})$ is "the obvious one"... Thankfully I found this post which explained it, and from this we get
$$ K=K_t(x_1^{1/p},\dots,x_m^{1/p}),\text{ where }p^m=[K:K_t].$$
In the forementioned post it's explained why these $x_i$ can be chosen in $K_0$. So now Serre says that $\rho_p$ is peu ramifiée if $v_p(x_i)\equiv 0\bmod{p}$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$; and très ramifiée otherwise.
For me, this definition is a bit unmotivated and I don't find it very intuitive. I know one can restate it in terms of algebraic geometry but that's too much for me right now. So we found this article, which relates Serre's definition of "peu ramifiée" and "très ramifiée" and the "jumps" in the filtration of higher ramification groups of the extension $K/K_0$, which I will denote by $G_i$ for all $i\geq-1$. It's not defined explicitly but the depth of the filtration is the unique integer $i$ such that $G_i\neq\{1\}$ and $G_{i+1}=\{1\}$. The problem is that in this article we are assuming that the image of $\rho_p$ is contained in $\mathrm{GL}_2({\mathbb F}_p)$, and not in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb F}_p)$, so it simplies a lot since $m=1$ with the above notation.
I was trying to check if it makes sense to say in the general case that $\rho_p$ is peu ramifiée if the depth of the filtration $\{G_i\}_{i\geq -1}$ is 1 and that it's très ramifiée otherwise. Does anybody know if this makes sense? I tried to replicate the proof of theorem 4.2 of the article assuming $[K:K_0]=p^m(p-1)$ but I had lots of doubts.
For example, I don't understand why "The action oftame ramification on wild ramification  forces the depth of the filtration to be either $1$ or $p$". Apparently this follows from the following proposition of Serre's "Local Fields" (page 69, proposition 9):
"Proposition 9. If $s\in G_0$ and $\tau\in G_{i}/G_{i+1}$, $i\geq 1$, then $\theta_i(s\tau s^{-1})=\theta_0(s)^i\theta_i(\tau)$".
How does the statement follows from this proposition? I assume that in my case I don't really have to use this proposition because previously we have studied the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(K_t/K_0)=G_0/G_1$ on $\rho_p(I_{p,w})=G_1$. Explicitly, if we take $$s=\begin{pmatrix}g^{\alpha+1} & * \\
0&g^{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix}\in G_0\text{ and }\,u=\begin{pmatrix}1&d\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}\in G_1$$
then we get
$$sus^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&gd\\
0&1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
I've been trying to think how to use this in order to show that the depth of filtration must be either $1$ or $p$ (or powers of $p$ less or equal than $p^m$ in my case, I'm not sure) but I got nowhere. If someone could help me with that, I'd appreciate it a lot.
The last doubt is the following: continuing with Serre's article, he says in a remark that "we always have $m=1$ or $m=2$: this can be seen using the action via $G_p$-conjugation on $\rho_p(I_{p,w})$" (page 186). Am I misstranslating this? Why is that the case? I haven't found any proof of that statement, and I think it would simplify some things trying to relate Serre's definition with Darrin Doud's definition.
Thank you so much for reading, any help will be appreciated.

Here's how to use the Proposition from Local Fields. Write $\nu$ for the upper-right entry of $\rho$.
Let $h \in G_i$ and $g \in I$ (where $I$ is the inertia group, and $\rho(G_{i+1})$ is trivial). Let $\nu$ be the upper-right coordinate of $\rho$.
Then $\rho(ghg^{-1}) = \begin{pmatrix}\chi^{\beta}(g) & \nu(g)\\ 0 & \chi^{\alpha}(g)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & \nu(h)\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \chi^{-\beta}(g) & \nu(g)\chi(g)^{-\alpha-\beta}\\ 0 & \chi(g)^{-\alpha}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \chi(g)^{\beta-\alpha}\nu(h)\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \chi(g)\nu(h)\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.
By Local Fields, Corollary 3 p.67, $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space, so it follows that conjugation by $G_0$ on $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is exactly given by multiplication by $\chi$.
When you compare to Proposition 9 p.69, you see that it is necessary that $\theta_0^i(g)=\chi(g)$ for all $g \in G_0$. This implies that (backtracking through the definitions) $i \equiv 1\pmod{p-1}$.
I'm not sure how to show directly that $i < p+1$. The argument I know is to go through the class field theory isomorphism, and show thanks to the exponential map on $\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)$ that every element in $1+\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)}^{p+1}\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p]$ is a $p$-th power, and therefore is in the kernel of (the counterpart of) $\nu$.
I dimly recall finding some sort of Galois-theoretic counterpart of the statement in Local Fields, but I can't find it, so maybe I misremember.
Class field theory also gives you a "nice" way to see that $m \leq 2$ once you know that $\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_1$.
Indeed, $\nu_{|G_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)}}$ is a character with the same image as $\nu$ (if necessary after modifying $\nu$ by an $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(\chi)$ coboundary), so corresponds to some $\nu_0: \mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)^{\times} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, with the same image as $\nu$. The cocycle relation translates to $\nu_0(\sigma(z))=\chi(\sigma)\nu_0(z)$. In particular, $\nu_0$ vanishes on all intermediary subfields.
Using the exponential, with $\omega$ some primitive $p$-th root of unity, $(\nu_0)_{|(\omega-1)^2\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p]}$ corresponds to a group homomorphism $\nu_1: (\omega-1)^2\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p] \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ such that $\nu_1(\sigma(z))=\chi(\sigma)\nu_1(z)$.
I claim that the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module $M=(\omega-1)^2\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p]$ is free of rank one over $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)/\mathbb{Q}_p)]$.
Indeed, $R$ is a finite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, both modules are free of rank $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and $t \in R \longmapsto t \cdot [p(1-\omega)] \in M$ is injective, so all the eigenspaces of $M$ are free of rank one over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
This implies that the image of $\nu_1$ is contained in a $\mathbb{F}_p$-line. Recall that $m$ is the dimension over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of the image of the wild inertia by $\nu$: so $m$ is the dimension over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $\nu_0(1+(\omega-1)\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p])$.
The conclusion follows since $\frac{1+(\omega-1)\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p]}{1+(\omega-1)^2\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_p]}$.

And I can't resist giving the proof that $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2$. Indeed, let $\epsilon=\chi\varepsilon_1/\varepsilon_2$. Then you can check (by using $\rho$) that $\nu(\sigma h\sigma^{-1})=\epsilon(\sigma)\nu(h)$ for any $\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $h \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/K_t)$.
Now, there is an identification isomorphism $C$ from $K_0^{\times} \otimes \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ to the space $S(1)$ of characters $g \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}(\mu_p)) \longmapsto g(x^{1/p})/x^{1/p} \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(1)$.
Or, in other words, there is an isomorphism $\kappa: S \rightarrow K_0^{\times} \otimes \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(-1)$.
For any $x \in K_0^{\times}$, if $\kappa_x$ is the attached Kummer character, then $\kappa_x(\sigma \cdot \sigma^{-1})=\chi(\sigma)\kappa_{\sigma^{-1}(x)}$.
Indeed, if $h \in I_p$, pick a $p$-th root $y$ of $x$. Then $\kappa(\sigma h \sigma^{-1}) = \frac{\sigma(h(\sigma^{-1}(y)))}{y}=\sigma\left(\frac{h(\sigma^{-1}(y))}{\sigma^{-1}(y)}\right) = \chi(\sigma)\kappa_{\sigma^{-1}(x)}(h)$, because $\sigma^{-1}(y)$ is a $p$-th root of $\sigma^{-1}(x)$.
In other words, $\kappa$ is $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$-equivariant, where $g$ turns $\nu' \in S$ into $\nu'(g^{-1}\cdot g)$.
Now, we have a projection $\pi: K_0^{\times}/K_0^{\times p}\otimes \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(-1) \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(-1)$ whose kernel is exactly the space of those characters that are ``peu ramifiés''.
Now, $\nu(g^{-1}\cdot g)=\epsilon^{-1}(g)\nu$ for any $g$. So if $\pi(\nu) \neq 0$, it follows that $\epsilon^{-1}(g)=\chi^{-1}(g)$.

Thank you so much for the detailed answer!
